# How to send email in queue in php

Tags: php

I am sending email using smptp.I want after 150 emails rest emails will add in queue and will send on next day automatically. How can i do this ?

Comment: It's a generic question, I think you have to be more specific. You can do it in different ways, you can save it in a txt, for example. Put a date to read it..

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is too broad, I would like to answer the minimal approach you can take.

Just follow the steps:

1. Add all emails to be send in database along with their content and receipt email address with bit field(column) `hasProcessed`
2. Read one by one row and as soon as you send email make `hasProcessed` true.
3. As soon as you process 150 rows (limit the database result set by 150) stop the script execution.
4. Make a cron job to run this script at specified time everyday.

> minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute

This is what cron-job Syntax look like.

Look more here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job